# Cannot get rules component to fire on Commerce Completing the checkout process

Tags: commerce, rules

I have a baffling situation. I created a nice little rules component that retrieves a list, using VBO, of published Drupal Commerce Product Display nodes with referenced product stock of zero or less. And then loops through that list unpublishing each node. This is how I built it - https://drupal.org/node/1345216#comment-8306801

This component works as expected when executing it by itself or when placing it in a rule with the "After updating an existing commerce product" and/or "After updating existing content" events. I cannot get it to run when attaching it to a "Completing the checkout process" event.

Any ideas? Is it a permissions issue, as in customer cannot run the component or access the VBO list?

Is there another event related to a customer completing an order that might work better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible the user doesn't have access to execute the rules component. You can check the permission in admin user permissions or on the rule component edit page.

Keep in mind the rules component will need to be attached to a reaction rule to fire on the checkout complete event.

Other than that, if the component can process the passed `$commerce_order` parameter (passed to checkout complete), then it should be ok.

Comment: The second point you mentioned, "on the rule component edit page" was the setting I needed. There is a toggle in the Settings fieldset that I had missed - '**Configure access for using this component with a permission.**' Allowing all users access lets the process work as intended. Thank you